# Run program by different network connection in Windows platform

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, wired

1. I am using Windows 7
2. There're two internet connections: (A) wired lan and (B) wireless lan
3. There're two programs I want to run: (1) outlook and (2) browser

Can I run outlook by wired lan and browser by wireless lan?

Comment: This would be better asked on SuperUser.  Voting to migrate

Answer (score 2):

Given the right environment, you can.

This assumes that

- Your wired and wireless network uses different network segments,
- You want to use outlook to an internal Exchange (or SMTP/IMAP) server
- This server is neither on your wired nor on your wireless network segments.

What you need to do is to set your default route to your wireless network and then add a static route to your exchange server to your routing table, specifying that it should use your wireless wired network. Check out the `route add` command for this.